# JUnit MockMvc issue?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have an issue with JUnit and MockMvc. Here is my code:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvcUser.perform(post("/user/adduser")
            .content(user)
            .contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    UserService userService = new UserService();
    String userId = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    User userObj = userService.findUserById(userId);
    // the userObj is null and I have no idea why
    MvcResult sessionIdObj = mockMvcLogin.perform(post("/login/authenticate")
            .param("username", userObj.getEmail())
            .param("password", userObj.getPassword())
            .contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```

When I add the user I can see the new entry in the database. When I want to search for it with findUserById I always get null. When I set a breakpoint there I will get the user object every time and the test works as designed. My problem is why do I always get null when I run the test without a breakpoint?

Here is the code of findUserById

```
public User findUserById(String id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            User user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

And I never get an exception. I hope you guys have an idea what's going on there.

Comment: What happens if you put a 200ms sleep before `userService.findUserById(userId);`?

Comment: For starters ditch the `HibernateUtil` class and use spring for session management and transaction management. You shouldn't be creating a new UserService either you should obtain it from the application context. But if you really want to check use a JdbcTemplate and simply issue an query instead of using the same technology you used to put it in there.

Comment: No change when I add a sleep